# The Feedback tag is kinda hilarious right now

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just poking around, and I noticed the [feedback](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback) tag seems to have multiple interpretations. Some think of it in terms of getting feedback from a person about their playing, and others use it in the context of getting feedback from sound equipment. Also, the tag itself doesn't actually have a description.

On the other hand, which interpretation is correct? I assume the one related to sound equipment, right? Should we have both?

Comment: Wanting feedback about [feedback]?

Comment: @cullub [Southern drawl] "That's funny right there..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is why it's always important for tags to have some kind of excerpt on the directed use of the tag. The intention is to use the feedback tag for the kind that is from a sound loop (i.e. from mics, guitars, ect) *not* to ask for constructive criticism (which is also a type of feedback). I've drafted a quick excerpt for the feedback tag:

> For questions about either wanted or unwanted sound loops via mics,
>   pickups, PAs, ect. Do not use for questions that request constructive
>   criticism or the like.

Feel free to improve the tag and start to add it where it belongs and remove it from questions where it doesn't.

---

As I side note, I would really be interested in doing a tag cleanup soon to find and fix more issues like this.

Comment: Nice.  I've removed it from the questions where it didn't fit.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it's called *audio feedback* or *acoustic feedback*. Do you think it's better to create either tag to make it clearer, and   synonimize *feedback* tag to the new one?

Comment: Tag clean-ups are great, but if tags aren't maintained, the problem will return. Get the community involved by letting users adopt important tags which is comonly misused. For instance, you adopt the feedback tag, the next guy adopt the guitar tag, etc. Everytime a question is tagged with your adopted tag, you can inspect it and then make a decision if the question is correctly tagged or not. This way, you wil ensure that this issue does not return

Comment: @AndrewT. Good call!  I've change the tag to the former name and synonymized the latter: https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/audio-feedback/synonyms.  Leaving out just `feedback` entirely since it will show these when typed and leave less room for confusion.